# How to provide gradient color for flutter splash screen

Tags: flutter

i am using the following plugin

`flutter_native_splash 2.2.17`

it is work perfectly but the problem is i only can use one color in the following `setup`

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#16874c" // here i am not able to use two HEX color as list in order to get gradiant color
```

i have the following desire gradient

```
  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Colors.blue,
              Colors.black,
            ]
        )
    ),
  ),
```

how can i use that same gradient and provide it to `flutter_native_splash` setup

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

```
  # color or background_image is the only required parameter.  Use color to set the background
  # of your splash screen to a solid color.  Use background_image to set the background of your
  # splash screen to a png image.  This is useful for gradients. The image will be stretch to the
  # size of the app. Only one parameter can be used, color and background_image cannot both be set.
  color: "#42a5f5"
  #background_image: "assets/background.png"
```

Create a gradient image with any tool, put it inside your assets folder and link it as background_image

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use gradient colors as your background color, you need to create a new file in the drawable folder and name it gradient_background.xml.

Since the gradient background is a combination of colors, specify the custom colors you want to use as a gradient in colors.xml. The maximum number of colors you can use is three: the start color, center color, and end color.

In this file, within the shape tag, specify your gradient. In my example, that’d be a linear gradient with all of the possible three colors.

To choose your gradient color and what angle of the gradient you want, you can use the Online [CSS Gradient Generator.](https://angrytools.com/gradient/)

for more info check this [article](https://betterprogramming.pub/customize-default-splash-screen-in-flutter-4f0a3d872377#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20use,as%20a%20gradient%20in%20colors.)